# Looking for free and secure peer-to-peer desktop sharing

Tags: screen-sharing

I am looking for a desktop sharing solution that will allow me to show my desktop to a remote user. The system must be

- free
- secure (some reasonable encryption)
- peer-to-peer (i.e., does not require some server in the middle)
- able to run on Windows and Mac
- easy enough so that I can send an invitation via e-mail and the invitee needs only click on something and say "OK" a couple of times

I realize this is asking for a lot, but I was hoping there is something out there that at least gets close to meeting these requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com) fits your requirements. You send the remote user the ID and password, and they connect. I even think there is a way to email the info to someone in the program.

Comment: Jacob, I use TeamViewer. +1

Comment: Is Teamviewer peer-to-peer? I went to their site and I could not tell if was or not.

Comment: Yes, it is, you connect to the server to get the ID, but thats it